# Load polygon / shapefile from GCP bucket directly Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to load JSON multipolygon directly from a GCP bucket file.
It actually works if the JSON is not too big, but does not work if the file become bigger.
Here is my code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b77179ab2b3518487f685ed2aec0e735

```
//var url = 'gs://test-public-gcp/bigfile.json';
var url = 'gs://test-public-gcp/smallfile.json';
var blob = ee.Blob(url);
var string = blob.string();
var json = ee.Deserializer.fromJSON(string.getInfo());
var polygon = ee.Geometry(json);
Map.addLayer(polygon);
```

Is there a size limit for ee.Deserializer.fromJSON ?
The small file is about 10 times smaller than the big file, and it loads in 2-3 seconds, the bigfile never loads (not even in 5 minutes).

A solution could be to split the bigfile into small files, but then I would need to list all files in a bucket folder to retrieve them all, is there a function that can list the files of a gcp bucket?

I could also import a shapefile from gcp bucket using startTableIngestion, but it does not work in the public app (since it creates an asset), is there a way to make it work in public app?

Overall, I am looking for any solution that would allow me to import a shapefile / JSON polygon as a new layer, directly from the public app. And using only function available in the GEE online code editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I solved my problem using:

```
var url = 'gs://test-public-gcp/bigfile2.txt';
var blob = ee.Blob(url); 
var geom = blob.string().decodeJSON();
var polygon = ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(geom); 
Map.addLayer(polygon);
```

And my `bigfile2.txt`is now just a file with the coordinates, like `[[[[150.33646898037068, -28.55949624210206],[150.33646898037068, -28.6312401012765],[150.4367192245113, -28.58723496827538],[150.40032701259724, -28.535369667334407]]],[[[150.47929124599568, -28.558290044640838],[150.49920396572224, -28.627623936423543],[150.54520921474568, -28.59145543753039],[150.54246263271443, -28.5480368082393]]]]`

Whether there exist a better solution remains an open question, but it works!